# unordered list not laying out correctly

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list that I want to show text blocks laid out in two columns.  The list lays out the items in two columns, but I'm finding that there is inconsistent spacing.  So the items on the right hand column are positioned one below another with the margin I have set, and on the left hand column, a large gap appears between the two items.

How can I fix this?  My HTML is below.  Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>test page
 <STYLE type="text/css">
 .textColumnBox {
padding-top:10px;
float: left;
width: 640px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.moreNews {
padding: 2px 0 5px 0;
width:630px;
display:block;
clear:both;
background-image: url(/images/footer.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: right;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
   .newscolumns
{
width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
vertical-align:top;
}

.newscolumns ul
{
height: 300px;  
font-size: 12pt;    
 vertical-align:top;
 margin:2px;

}

 .newscolumns ul li
{
 padding: inherit;
 width: 310px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: -4px;
 background: red;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
.newsBox 
{
margin-left: 3px;
margin-bottom: 2px;/*changed from 15*/
padding-right: 20px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #4E4629;
}
.newsBox p {
display:block;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.2em;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.newsBox h3 {
line-height: 1.2em;
}

.newsBoxFoot {
display:block;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.4em;
color:#999;

}
.newsBox a {
text-decoration:none;

}
.newsBox a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
 </STYLE></head>
<body>
 <div class="textColumnBox">
    <h1>
        Latest News</h1>
    <div class="newscolumns">
        <ul>
            <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">sample text here qwertyuiowertyuiwertyu</a></h3>
        <p>kfdokashfsdhfjhf kjashf kjash fkjsahf saf kjsh fjsakhf kjashf kjsahf kjsahfjksafiksafkashf hsf haskjhf askjhf asjlkh flsakh flskahf lkashf lkashf lksahf lkashf lkashjh as</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">20/12/2011 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li> 
  <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">yasdefghasdfgh sdfgsdfgasdfga dfgsdfgsdf sdfghsdefgh</a></h3>
        <p>Pkjhfsdfh skljfhsakjfh asjklhfasljkfh aslkf salkhf laskhf lskahf 
        lkasflkashfl ksahflk aslfk aslf hsalkf aslkhf laskhf lskahf glksahf 
        lskahf laskhf lksahf asljkf hsalkhflskahflkh&nbsp; sa</p>
        <p>ewreewrewr</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <div class="newsBoxFoot">14/06/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>
 <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">gdfgfdg dfgfdgfgfdgdfg fdgfdgfdgfd gfdgfdgdfdfr</a></h3>
        <p>;sdljfs;dlj sd;lfj ds;pl;lsdjg;kdlgkdsflblkjg dlskh gkhkljh kjl.h k.j hgjklsdh g kjdsh g,m hcnxogv;isdhgoiunndkn  o;jyhds</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">04/04/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>
 <li>
        <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">dfgfdg dfgdfgdfg fddfg</a></h3>
        <p>sd;l;ljd;l sdkjfdskjlsdkjfldksjflsdkjflsdkjf sldkhfdslkhfjkldhf 
        sdkjhkjh skdjhfkjhkjdhk skdjhkjhkjhoswlhf lkhkljhs kjhkjhkjh 
        sdklhkjh kh</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">14/06/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>



       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="moreNews">more news</div>
    <!-- end .textColumnBox -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive tried with all the css tweaks people have sent and it doesnt seem to work (but thanks to those who responded).  I guess I will have to resort to a table! :(

Answer (score 1):

Your width of li is the issue here.

[See demo](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8m)

```
.textColumnBox {
  padding-top:10px;
  float: left;
  width: 640px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.moreNews {
  padding: 2px 0 5px 0;
  width:630px;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  background-image: url(/images/footer.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-align: right;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.newscolumns
{
  width: 100%;

  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.newscolumns ul
{
  height: 300px;

  font-size: 12pt;

  vertical-align:top;
  margin:2px;

}

.newscolumns ul li
{
  padding: inherit;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.newsBox 
{
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  /*changed from 15*/
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: #4E4629;

}
.newsBox p {
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
.newsBox h3 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.newsBoxFoot {
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color:#999;

}
.newsBox a {
  text-decoration:none;

}
.newsBox a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFF;
}

<div class="textColumnBox">
  <h1>
    Latest News
  </h1>
  <div class="newscolumns">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="newsBox">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">
              sample text here qwertyuiowertyuiwertyu
          </a>
      </h3>
      <p>
        kfdokashfsdhfjhf kjashf kjash fkjsahf saf kjsh fjsakhf kjashf kjsahf kjsahfjksafiksafkashf hsf haskjhf askjhf asjlkh flsakh flskahf lkashf lkashf lksahf lkashf lkashjh as
      </p>
      <div class="newsBoxFoot">
        20/12/2011 read more
      </div>
      <!-- end .newsBox -->
              </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="newsBox">
              <h3>
                <a href="#">
                  yasdefghasdfgh sdfgsdfgasdfga dfgsdfgsdf sdfghsdefgh
                </a>
              </h3>
              <p>
                Pkjhfsdfh skljfhsakjfh asjklhfasljkfh aslkf salkhf laskhf lskahf 
                lkasflkashfl ksahflk aslfk aslf hsalkf aslkhf laskhf lskahf glksahf 
                lskahf laskhf lksahf asljkf hsalkhflskahflkh&nbsp; sa
              </p>
              <p>
                ewreewrewr
              </p>
              <p>
                &nbsp;
              </p>

              <div class="newsBoxFoot">
                14/06/2012 read more
              </div>
              <!-- end .newsBox -->
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="newsBox">
              <h3>
                <a href="#">
                  gdfgfdg dfgfdgfgfdgdfg fdgfdgfdgfd gfdgfdgdfdfr
                </a>
              </h3>
              <p>
                ;sdljfs;dlj sd;lfj ds;pl;lsdjg;kdlgkdsflblkjg dlskh gkhkljh kjl.h k.j hgjklsdh g kjdsh g,m hcnxogv;isdhgoiunndkn  o;jyhds
              </p>
              <div class="newsBoxFoot">
                04/04/2012 read more
              </div>
              <!-- end .newsBox -->
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="newsBox">
              <h3>
                <a href="#">
                  dfgfdg dfgdfgdfg fddfg
                </a>
              </h3>
              <p>
                sd;l;ljd;l sdkjfdskjlsdkjfldksjflsdkjflsdkjf sldkhfdslkhfjkldhf 
                sdkjhkjh skdjhfkjhkjdhk skdjhkjhkjhoswlhf lkhkljhs kjhkjhkjh 
                sdklhkjh kh
              </p>
              <div class="newsBoxFoot">
                14/06/2012 read more
              </div>
              <!-- end .newsBox -->
            </div>
          </li>



      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="moreNews">
    more news
  </div>
  <!-- end .textColumnBox -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see two columns. Just "Latest News", a bit under it a big red box with some text, but every line in it has a different row.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/WekcnbhE

**HTML**

```
<div class="textColumnBox">
    <h1>
        Latest News</h1>
    <div class="newscolumns">
        <ul>
            <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">sample text here qwertyuiowertyuiwertyu</a></h3>
        <p>kfdokashfsdhfjhf kjashf kjash fkjsahf saf kjsh fjsakhf kjashf kjsahf kjsahfjksafiksafkashf hsf haskjhf askjhf asjlkh flsakh flskahf lkashf lkashf lksahf lkashf lkashjh as</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">20/12/2011 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li> 
  <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">yasdefghasdfgh sdfgsdfgasdfga dfgsdfgsdf sdfghsdefgh</a></h3>
        <p>Pkjhfsdfh skljfhsakjfh asjklhfasljkfh aslkf salkhf laskhf lskahf 
        lkasflkashfl ksahflk aslfk aslf hsalkf aslkhf laskhf lskahf glksahf 
        lskahf laskhf lksahf asljkf hsalkhflskahflkh&nbsp; sa</p>
        <p>ewreewrewr</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <div class="newsBoxFoot">14/06/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>
 <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">gdfgfdg dfgfdgfgfdgdfg fdgfdgfdgfd gfdgfdgdfdfr</a></h3>
        <p>;sdljfs;dlj sd;lfj ds;pl;lsdjg;kdlgkdsflblkjg dlskh gkhkljh kjl.h k.j hgjklsdh g kjdsh g,m hcnxogv;isdhgoiunndkn  o;jyhds</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">04/04/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>
 <li>
        <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">dfgfdg dfgdfgdfg fddfg</a></h3>
        <p>sd;l;ljd;l sdkjfdskjlsdkjfldksjflsdkjflsdkjf sldkhfdslkhfjkldhf 
        sdkjhkjh skdjhfkjhkjdhk skdjhkjhkjhoswlhf lkhkljhs kjhkjhkjh 
        sdklhkjh kh</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">14/06/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>



       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="moreNews">more news</div>
    <!-- end .textColumnBox -->
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textColumnBox {

float: left;
width: 640px;

}
.moreNews {

width:630px;
display:block;
clear:both;
background-image: url(/images/footer.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: right;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
   .newscolumns
{
width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
background:red;
}

.newscolumns ul
{
font-size: 12pt; 
  margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

 .newscolumns ul li
{

 width: 270px;
 float: left;
list-style-type: none;
margin:0px 20px;
  padding:0;

 }
.newscolumns ul li:nth-child(odd)
{


  border-right:1px solid black;
 }

.newsBox p {
display:block;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.2em;

}
.newsBox h3 {
line-height: 1.2em;
}

.newsBoxFoot {
display:block;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.4em;
color:#999;

}
.newsBox a {
text-decoration:none;

}
.newsBox a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: the problem is this css applies to dynamically generated content.  If on the second list itme I take out the extra paragraphs, the layout resorts back to the odd layout I had to begin with.  So trying the css changes on my dynamic content gives the odd layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think now i change some codings, now u try it


<html>
<head>test page
 <STYLE type="text/css">
 .textColumnBox {
padding-top:10px;

margin:0px auto;
width: 640px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.moreNews {
padding: 2px 0 5px 0;
width:630px;
display:block;
clear:both;
background-image: url(/images/footer.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: right;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
   .newscolumns
{
width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
vertical-align:top;
}

.newscolumns ul
{
height: 300px;  
font-size: 12pt;    
 vertical-align:top;
 margin:2px;
 padding:0px;

}

 .newscolumns ul li
{
 padding: inherit;
 width: 310px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background: red;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
.newsBox 
{
margin-left: 3px;
margin-bottom: 2px;/*changed from 15*/
padding-right: 20px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #4E4629;
}
.newsBox p {
display:block;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.2em;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.newsBox h3 {
line-height: 1.2em;
}

.newsBoxFoot {
display:block;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.4em;
color:#999;

}
.newsBox a {
text-decoration:none;

}
.newsBox a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
p
{
    margin:0px;
}
 </STYLE></head>
<body>
 <div class="textColumnBox">
    <h1>
        Latest News</h1>
    <div class="newscolumns">
        <ul>
            <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">sample text here qwertyuiowertyuiwertyu</a></h3>
        <p>kfdokashfsdhfjhf kjashf kjash fkjsahf saf kjsh fjsakhf kjashf kjsahf kjsahfjksafiksafkashf hsf haskjhf askjhf asjlkh flsakh flskahf lkashf lkashf lksahf lkashf lkashjh as</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">20/12/2011 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li> 
  <li style="float:right;" >
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">yasdefghasdfgh sdfgsdfgasdfga dfgsdfgsdf sdfghsdefgh</a></h3>
        <p>Pkjhfsdfh skljfhsakjfh asjklhfasljkfh aslkf salkhf laskhf lskahf 
        lkasflkashfl ksahflk aslfk aslf hsalkf aslkhf laskhf lskahf glksahf 
        lskahf laskhf lksahf asljkf hsalkhflskahflkh&nbsp; sa</p>



        <div class="newsBoxFoot">14/06/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>
 <li>
    <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">gdfgfdg dfgfdgfgfdgdfg fdgfdgfdgfd gfdgfdgdfdfr</a></h3>
        <p>;sdljfs;dlj sd;lfj ds;pl;lsdjg;kdlgkdsflblkjg dlskh gkhkljh kjl.h k.j hgjklsdh g kjdsh g,m hcnxogv;isdhgoiunndkn  o;jyhds</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">04/04/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>
 <li style="float:right;">
        <div class="newsBox">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">dfgfdg dfgdfgdfg fddfg</a></h3>
        <p>sd;l;ljd;l sdkjfdskjlsdkjfldksjflsdkjflsdkjf sldkhfdslkhfjkldhf 
        sdkjhkjh skdjhfkjhkjdhk skdjhkjhkjhoswlhf lkhkljhs kjhkjhkjh 
        sdklhkjh kh</p>
        <div class="newsBoxFoot">14/06/2012 read more</div>
        <!-- end .newsBox -->
    </div>
</li>



       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="moreNews">more news</div>
    <!-- end .textColumnBox -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```